# Subgroup of finite index in mathematical writing

Tags: mathematics

I have a question about mathematical writing. A group G can have a subgroup H and every subgroup H has a so called *index* in G, which is a number (finite or infinite) and depends on both G and H and is written [H : G].

Which of the following two version is better?

> **A:** For every subgroup H of finite index in G there exists a subgroup J of finite index in H such that ...

or

> **B:** For every subgroup H in G of finite index there exists a subgroup J in H  of finite index such that ...

I personally find the first one more logical but the second one better to read because it is immeditately clear that H is a subgroup of G. Is it bad style in the second version to write "of finite index" after specifying the subgroup itself?

Comment: I'd split up the noun phrases differently. _For every subgroup of finite index H in G, there exists a subgroup of finite index J in H, such that ..._

Comment: You will probaly get more accurate advice if you ask this on a specialist website, like [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) because they'll know their own style much better. Also, look at how other mathematicians write it (google subgroup finite index). That said. rewording a lot more may help (like John's comment). But frankly, both are fine. I might be more likely to say subgroup H __of__ G, but people use __in__ all the time too.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you, I like this too and I think I will use this version of yours now. The reason I did not include it in the first place is that I initially thought one might mistake "of finite index H" to mean that H itself should be the index, but I think the danger is probably very low, especially because H is an uppercase letter and numbers are usually denoted by lowercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematician here! I have seen the "less than or equal to" sign (⩽) occasionally used to mean "subgroup". So, you could write your statement as:

"Given a group G, for every H⩽G of finite index there exists J⩽H of finite index such that ..."

You could, of course, first define your own notation for subgroup and use that instead. I believe this is best because it makes it clear that you're talking about subgroups with finite index. I doubt that any mathematician reading this would have an issue understanding it.